# Stats collector/aggregator to send to Influx?

Tags: tags, metrics, influxdb, appstats

I need to replace an old stats collector that receives stats from a number of apps, does a bit of aggregation (and maybe sorting), and then sends the processed stats onto influx.

The requirements that I have at the moment are that the application/service should make use of tags and loosely follow the [metrics 2.0 format](http://metrics20.org/spec/).

The frontend will be implemented in Erlang, but I can always make a small API to deal with small changes.

Apologies if I've used the wrong terminology or don't make sense in some places, I'm still relatively new in most of these areas.

Comment: The requirement "follow the metrics 2.0" sucks, because it probably means that you are limited with tools [listed here](http://metrics20.org/implementations/).

Comment: @WindyFields I can always pop a little wrapper around something to get it in the right format. Checking out Riemann atm, looking positive...

Comment: The standard metrics collector for InfluxDB is defacto [Telegraf](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf). It has many plugins for various input formats as well as for basic aggregation and processing. Though, I am not sure if that is what you've asked for.